# How do you localize ECB custom actions?

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, display-template, custom-actions, ecb-menu

I have created two custom action buttons using javascript but they need to be localized (fr/en). I have server side Resource files and client side ones as well.

This is how I'm creating the actions:

```
        var excludeAction = actionCollection.add();
        excludeAction.set_location(actions.location);
        excludeAction.set_registrationId(actions.registrationId);
        excludeAction.set_registrationType(actions.registrationType);
        excludeAction.set_sequence(101);
        excludeAction.set_title("My Custom Action);
        excludeAction.set_url("javascript:cca.pac.exclude(true, {ItemId})");
        excludeAction.set_rights(permissions);
        excludeAction.update();
```

Right now I'm hard coding `My Custom Action`, how could I handle translation when the site is in French?